# jqueryUI, accept if 'drop to' container meets requirements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

the JqueryUi documentation mentions that there is a way to check if element that user 'drag and drop' meets the requiremments by using:

```
accept: function(el) {
    return CHECK_REQUIREMENTS;
}
```

but how is it possible to check if the target element (the container the user is trying to place the item into) that meets some criteria?

My code is:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        
        <style>
            * * {
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .search-container {
              display: flex;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              width: 33%;
              min-height: 200px;
              border: 1px solid red;
            }

            .search-item {
              border: 1px solid grey;
              text-align: center;
              margin: 5px;
              width: 150px;
              max-width: 300px;
              flex-basis: 150px;
              flex-grow: 1;
              height: 80px;
            }
        </style>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="myContainer">
        
            <div id="firstContainer" class="search-container acceptableContainer" style="float:left">
              <div class="search-item acceptable">first</div>
              <div class="search-item acceptable">two</div>
              <div class="search-item acceptable">three</div>
              <div class="search-item acceptable">four</div>
              <div class="search-item acceptable">five</div>
              <div class="search-item">six</div>
              <div class="search-item">seven</div>
              <div class="search-item">eight</div>
              <div class="search-item">nine</div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="secondContainer" class="search-container" style="float:left">
            </div>
            
            <div id="thirdContainer" class="search-container acceptableContainer">
            </div>
        
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
        
        $(".search-item").draggable({ 
            revert: 'invalid'
        });
        
        $(".search-container").droppable({
            accept: function(el) {
                return el.hasClass('acceptable');
            },
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
               var droppable = $(this);
               var draggable = ui.draggable;
               draggable.appendTo(droppable);
               draggable.css({top: '0px', left: '0px'});
            }
        }); 
        
    </script>
    
</html>
```

So this code checks if 'drag and drop' has class `acceptable`.

For example, I would like to check if target container has class `acceptableContainer` and accept the operation only if it returns true (so `secondContainer` can not be target container).

How is it posisble to deal with that?

Comment: why not use `.droppable` on `.acceptableContainer` itself?

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner I need to check more complicated condition based on the element that  should be dropped and the target container. So I need to have an access to both of the elements in one function that will revert operation if needed. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside .drop event, you check the condition and if met, then proceed with the operation like appending to new location etc. Also modify css properties to match positioning in new location, and if conditions are not met, set the 'revert' option of draggable to 'true',
**Below part might not be necessary**  I got mixed results
[then reset it to 'invalid' inside .stop event of draggable. Key is .stop of draggable is called after .drop of droppable.]

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Droppable </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerylib/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="jquerylib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquerylib/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />-->
    <style>
        .boxMain {
            width: 40%;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 3px solid black;
            color: black;
            margin: 0px auto;
            /*padding: 15% 15% 0% 15%;*/
            float: left;
        }

        .box {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: lightpink;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 15px;
            color: white;
            margin: 5px;
            z-index: 99;
            float: left;
            /*position: absolute;*/
        }
    </style>

    <!--<script src="script/02droppable.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".box").draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                stop: function () {
                    console.log("stopped");
                    $(this).draggable("option", "revert", "invalid");

                }
            });
            $(".boxMain").droppable({
                accept: ".box",
                drop: function (e, u) {
                    console.log("dropped");
                    if ($(this).hasClass("AcceptingBox")) {
                        u.draggable.appendTo($(this));
                        u.draggable.css({
                            "left": 0,
                            "top": 0
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("No");
                        u.draggable.draggable("option", "revert", true);
                    }
                }
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="height:200px;">
        <div id="sub1" class="box" style="background: red"></div>
        <div id="sub2" class="box" style="background: green"></div>
        <div id="sub3" class="box" style="background: blue"><p>Click</p></div>
        <div id="sub4" class="box" style="background: aqua"><p>Click</p></div>

    </div>
    <div id="main1" class="boxMain AcceptingBox">Accepting</div>
    <div id="main2" class="boxMain"></div>
    <!--<div id="main2" class="boxMain"></div>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does anyone know why am I getting this error in jfiddle? **$(...).draggable is not a function** even after selecting javascript + jquery for script window?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".search-item").draggable({
    revert: 'valid'
  });

  $(".search-container").droppable({
    accept: '.acceptable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var droppable = $(this);
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      if (droppable.hasClass("acceptableContainer")) {
        draggable.appendTo(droppable);
        draggable.css({
          top: '0px',
          left: '0px'
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.search-item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex-basis: 150px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="myContainer">

  <div id="firstContainer" class="search-container acceptableContainer" style="float:left">
    <div class="search-item acceptable">first</div>
    <div class="search-item acceptable">two</div>
    <div class="search-item acceptable">three</div>
    <div class="search-item acceptable">four</div>
    <div class="search-item acceptable">five</div>
    <div class="search-item">six</div>
    <div class="search-item">seven</div>
    <div class="search-item">eight</div>
    <div class="search-item">nine</div>
  </div>

  <div id="secondContainer" class="search-container" style="float:left">
  </div>

  <div id="thirdContainer" class="search-container acceptableContainer">
  </div>

</div>
```

You will need to return a `false` to invoke the revert upon drop. It's sort of backward logic.